# why can not use property instead of __construct?

Tags: php, oop

starting use oop

why:

```
class user 
{
    private $pdo;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = singleton::get_instance()->PDO_connection();
    }

...
}
```

this works fine. but this:

```
class user 
{
    private $pdo = singleton::get_instance()->PDO_connection();

...
}
```

this does not working. Error `parse error, expecting ','' or ';'' in ...`

what is wrong with second variant?

Comment: `[php][oop basics]` in the title is not necessary, that's what tags are for.

Comment: Please note, that [php][oop basics] in the question title are unnecessary and redundant.  That's that point of using tags.  Someone with more rep that I have will eventually edit the title, but I thought you should know for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the last sentence of the first paragraph of [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) in the [PHP OOP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php):

> Class member variables are called
>   "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as
>   "attributes" or "fields", but for the
>   purposes of this reference we will use
>   "properties". They are defined by
>   using one of the keywords public,
>   protected, or private, followed by a
>   normal variable declaration. This
>   declaration may include an
>   initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be
>   evaluated at compile time and must not
>   depend on run-time information in
>   order to be evaluated.

In other words, the database handler returned by this statement is *not* a constant value and therefore will not be available at compile time:

```
singleton::get_instance()->PDO_connection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class properties cannot be assigned at declaration using functions.  Scalar values, constants (though not constants of the current class), and arrays only.